# jquery show-hide div with $(window).resize relative tollerance of e.g. +/-10px?

Tags: android, jquery, html, resize, show-hide

This is part of the jquery script I use to automatically show-hide sidebar based on screen size, both on document load and afterwards during screen/browser resize (e.g. landscape-portrait modes). Yes, I use it in combination with @media queries, but that is not the issue here. jQuery is needed to do the auto part and for toggling (not shown here).

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var sidebar = $("#sidebar");
        var advsearch = $("#advsearch");
// auto-hide function
        var resize = function() {
            if( $(window).width() > 650 ) {
                sidebar.show();
                advsearch.hide();
            } else {
                sidebar.hide();
                advsearch.show();
            }
        };
        resize();
        $(window).resize(resize);
    });
</script>
```

The problem exists with some Android 2.1 devices and their stock browser. The above script automatically hides sidebar on a slightest screen size change (function updates and continuosly monitors user's screen size), and when I browse the page and toggle to show sidebar, the smallest scroll on page triggers jquery function, which 'thinks' the screen resolution has changed and revisits the function - effectivle hiding again sidebar that was just toggled/activated!

Reason for this is most probably because of Android 2.1 browser's vertical scroll bar that somehow affects screen size during page vertical scroll, so the content of sidebar div can never be properly reached by the user. This does not happen in newer versions/devices, but it is annoying.

Solutions:

Basic idea is to drop later part of the jquery code and make the script less 'smart' (solution I currently use).

Second idea is to retain jquery auto-hide function, but to add some tollerance to the $(window).resize function. E.g. when the screen is resized up to +/-10px from the current size (whichever it is), resize function will not be triggered.

For example, let us say current screen size is 400px, so the condition to hide sidebar by above function is fullfilled (again doesn't matter if sidebar div was displayed or hiden before via toggle button for e.g.), it will NOT be hidden untill window/screen size of the device/browser does not pass 389px or beyond 411px.

I have trouble creating the logic that will set up a range condition for resize function. Also, another problem would be how to temporarely fix comparing variables (390px and 410px in above example), because the moment screen changes, the variables used for relative comparison will be recalculated.

Any idea for this solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I Don't think it's a good solution, but wouldn't this simple logic solve your problem?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var sidebar = $("#sidebar");
    var advsearch = $("#advsearch");
    var currentSize = 0;
    // auto-hide function
    var resize = function() {
      currentSize = $(window).width();
      if( currentSize > 650 ) {
        sidebar.show();
        advsearch.hide();
      } else {
        sidebar.hide();
        advsearch.show();
      }
    };
    resize();
    $(window).resize(function(){
      if ( (currentSize + 10) < $(window).width()) || (currentSize - 10) > $(window).width())){
        resize();
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi climbinghobo, thanks for willing to help. Unfortunatelly no, since there is an issue with currentSize that constantly updates (which btw is not defined above + there are some parenthesis missing etc.). If you change the screen for just 1px, in the next loop it will get new values and retriger the function.